# "Allow spacing between cells" set to false in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Basically, trying to turn this option off using VBA. There are workarounds using default styles but then I'd have to distribute those to every workstation. Would be better to handle it programmatically.

I went it off because it makes tables look like garbage. What I've tried:

```
wd.ActiveDocument.Tables(c).Spacing = CentimetersToPoints(0)
wd.ActiveDocument.Tables(c).Spacing = 0
```

Doesn't actually get rid of the spacing like setting it to false does.

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogTableTableOptions)
    .AllowSpacing = -1
    .Execute
End With
```

Doesn't do anything that I can discern.

Any other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet again, stumble across the solution right after posting:

```
' Turn off cell spacing to get around some formatting issues
With wd.Dialogs(wdDialogTableTableOptions)
    .AllowSpacing = False
    .Execute
End With
```

In my case, I created the Word.Application object from Access and neglected to put the `wd.` object on it... oops.